# CKEditor - Possible to have context menu for basic styles?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Is it possible to have basic styles(like bold, italic, underline, etc) in right click context menu?

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/addon/contextmenu

Comment: I have downloaded that plugin. But how exactly I get menu visible? I could just see the menu item for cut, copy and paste.

Comment: for custom plugin, I am able to add new menu item using addMenuItem. But how to do for out of the box plugin like bolt, underline etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it is.
Firstly, you have to add context menu group and items. For example,

```
editor.addMenuGroup('basicstyles', 1);
    editor.addMenuItems( {
        'bold': {
        label: 'Make it bold!',
        command: 'bold',
        group: 'basicstyles'
        } // add here more buttons like this
    } );
```

Next, you need to add context menu listeners.Simply, it looks like:

```
editor.contextMenu.addListener( function( element, selection ) {
    return {
        bold: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF // , anotherCommand:CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF, etc 
    }
} );
```

Done! You'll need to get some more complicated logic for listeners. See `plugin.js` code in `clipboard` plugin for example.